# Should I be merging Core data and syncing with a website?

Tags: json, core-data, synchronization

I don't quite understand syncing between apps and the web or what I'm meant to do with the data.

You have a `website` which talks to your `iphone` app, the app downloads say a JSON file but what changes is it meant to do with the Core data database?

What checks should I be doing?
Should I be merging, replacing, inserting data from the JSON file into Core data or assume that the JSON file is always up to date and always do a replace?

This also gets confusing when the app's data is changed.  How do you know which is the up to date version and which is not?

Perhaps I am over-confusing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What checks should I be doing? Should I be merging, replacing, inserting data from the JSON file into Core data or assume that the JSON file is always up to date and always do a replace?

Only you can really answer that. It depends on what your app does and what the web site does. It depends on what the data is, who updates it, and where and how they do so. There is no single right answer to your question. Define what your app needs to do and how it interacts with this web site, and the answers will follow from that. Is the JSON up to date? It might be or it might not-- that's not a technical question, it's a question of when and how data can be changed. It's part of the process that drives your app and site.